# Exporting table to CSV using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, csv

I'm having hard times exporting DB table in CSV file using LINQ. I've tried few things from related topics, but it was all way too long and I need a simpliest solution. There has to be something. 
With this code is problem, that file is created, but empty. When I tried to debug, query is fine, there's everything I want to export. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.csv");
        DataDataContext db = new DataDataContext();

        var query = from x in db.Zbozis
                    orderby x.Id
                    select x;

        foreach (var something in query)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(something.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Edit: Ok, I tried all your suggestions, sadly with same result (CSV was created, but in it was 10x Lekarna.Zbozi (Name of project/db + name of table)).
So I used a method, that I've found (why reinventing a wheel, huh).

```
public string ConvertToCSV(IQueryable query, string replacementDelimiter)
    {

        // Create the csv by looping through each row and then each field in each row
        // seperating the columns by commas

        // String builder for our header row
        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();

        // Get the properties (aka columns) to set in the header row
        PropertyInfo[] rowPropertyInfos = null;
        rowPropertyInfos = query.ElementType.GetProperties();

        // Setup header row 
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in rowPropertyInfos)
        {
            if (info.CanRead)
            {
                header.Append(info.Name + ",");
            }
        }

        // New row
        header.Append("\r\n");

        // String builder for our data rows
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        // Setup data rows
        foreach (var myObject in query)
        {

            // Loop through fields in each row seperating each by commas and replacing 
            // any commas in each field name with replacement delimiter
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in rowPropertyInfos)
            {
                if (info.CanRead)
                {

                    // Get the fields value and then replace any commas with the replacement delimeter
                    string tmp = Convert.ToString(info.GetValue(myObject, null));
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
                    {
                        tmp.Replace(",", replacementDelimiter);
                    }
                    data.Append(tmp + ",");
                }
            }

            // New row
            data.Append("\r\n");
        }

        // Check the data results... if they are empty then return an empty string
        // otherwise append the data to the header
        string result = data.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) == false)
        {
            header.Append(result);
            return header.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

So I have a modified version of previous code:

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("pokus.csv");
        ExportToCSV ex = new ExportToCSV();
        var query = from x in db.Zbozis
                    orderby x.Id
                    select x;
        string s = ex.ConvertToCSV(query,"; ");

        sw.WriteLine(s);
        sw.Flush();
```

Everything is fine, except it export every line in one column and does not separate it. See here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSNK0.jpg
Question is obvious then, how to divide it into columns like I have in my DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the file. Either use **"using"**

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
{
     ..............
}
```

or  simply try this

```
File.WriteAllLines("test.csv",query);
```

Comment: I tried it, but some other problems occured viz. my editet post

Comment: @Manik `I tried it, but some other problems occured` Thank for this magic explanation. Let me guess something: Are you sure your object ( in `select x;`) implements `ToString()` correctly (since you want to write it simply by doing `ToString()`). Otherwise you have to convert its properties explicitly to string with some code.

Comment: My other problem is described in my first edited post. If my object implements ToString ain't gonna be an issue in this case I think.